# Expurgo automático tabela - erro 1442

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho um processo automático que roda todos os dias, pegando algumas informações e guardando no banco de dados. Para ter um controle do que foi processo eu criei um tabela de log, onde eu guardo algumas informações como: `id_log`, `dt_log`, `hr_log`, `ds_body`, `ds_response`, mas essa tabela está ficando muito grande e preciso realizar um expurgo de informações automático, para isso eu criei uma trigger que é esse executada assim que um registro é inserido na tabela de log.

```
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS LimpaTabela_atm_logs;
```

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER LimpaTabela_atm_logs BEFORE INSERT ON `atm_logs`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE count_logs INT;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO count_logs FROM atm_logs WHERE dt_log < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 70 DAY);

```
    IF count_logs != 0 THEN
        DELETE FROM atm_logs WHERE dt_log <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 70 DAY);
    END IF;
END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

Mas na hora que executa a trigger é informado o erro 1442 - can't update table e o processo não é realizado.
Como posso sanar esse erro.

Comment: Uma pergunta sobre o assunto ja foi criada, se precisa comentar [continue na original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/586256/3635).